# How do I add a trigger to populate ModifiedDate

Tags: t-sql, triggers, last-modified

is it possible to have the ModifiedDate automatically update with the CurrentDateTime when the row has been updated/changed?

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[PK]
      ,[Iteration]
      ,[Exam01]
      ,[Exam02]
      ,[Exam03]
      ,[Exam04]
      ,[Exam05]
      ,[Exam06]
      ,[Exam07]
      ,[Exam08]
      ,[Exam09]
      ,[Exam10]
      ,[Exam11]
      ,[Exam12]
      ,[Exam13]
      ,[Exam14]
      ,[HRGCode]
      ,[AgeStart]
      ,[AgeEnd]
      ,[CreateDate]
      ,[ModifiedDate] --- Need this to update when the row is Modified!
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[Comments]
  FROM [CommDB].[dbo].[tblRadiologyNucMedLookup] c
  order by ID
```

Comment: You do not need a trigger for this.  Add a ModifiedDate = GetDate() to your UPDATE statement.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a trigger for this? You can have that column in the same `UPDATE` statement like

```
update tblRadiologyNucMedLookup 
set Iteration = 10,
[ModifiedDate] = getdate()
where ID = 101;
```